# BadMethodCallException en Notificaciones Laravel

Tags: laravel, notificaciones

Hola estoy creando unas notificaciones que deben ir a 3 registros de diferentes tablas en este Caso Promotor, Agente y Administradores y tengo el siguiente código:

```
$getClient = Client::where( 'sku', '=', $event->affilate->numCont )->first();

        $promotor = Promoter::where( 'id', '=', $getClient->promoter_id )->first();
        Notification::send( $promotor, new AffilateNotification( $event->affilate, $event->action, Auth::id() ) );
    
        Agent::where( 'id', '=', $getClient->agent_id )->each( function ( Agent $agent ) use ( $event ) {
            Notification::send( $agent, new AffilateNotification( $event->affilate, $event->action, Auth::id() ) );
        } );

        User::where( 'role_id', '=', UserRol::ROL_ADMINISTRADOR )->whereNotIn( 'id', [ Auth::id() ] )->each( function ( User $user ) use ( $event ) {
            Notification::send( $user, new AffilateNotification( $event->affilate, $event->action, Auth::id() ) );
        } );
```

Donde primero obtengo el numero de contrato de ahí saco el id del promotor y del agente al que pertenece ese contrato y luego intento enviar las notificaciones correspondientes pero al menos en la parte de del promotor me da el error:

Call to undefined method App\Model\Promoter::routeNotificationFor();

el USER::bla bla bla si funciona pero ese envia a todos los administradores.

si alguien me puede orientar se los agradeceria.

Que tengan excelente Semana!

Answer (score 0):

El problema fue que no tenía use Notifiable en mis modelos que serían notificados por eso me marcaba ese error